# disable submit button on some text field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

This is my html code for form

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
    <table style="border: 1px solid black;padding:20px;" cellspacing="1px">
        </br>
        </br>
        <tr>
            <td>Issue No:</td>
            <td>
                <input name="issueno" type="text" id="issueno" />
            </td>
            <td>Issue Date:</td>
            <td>
                <input name="issuedate" type="date" id="issuedate" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </br>
        </br>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item Code:</td>
            <td>
                <input name="itemcode" type="text" id="itemcode" />
            </td>
            <td>Description:</td>
            <td>
                <input name="des" type="text" style="width:250px; height:23px" id="desc" />
            </td>
            <td>Bal Quantity:</td>
            <td>
                <input name="bal" type="text" id="bal" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </br>
        <tr>
            <td>Issue Quantity:</td>
            <td>
                <input name="issuequ" type="text" id="issuequ" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </br>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Remark:</td>
            <td>
                <input name="remark" type="text" style="width:250px; height:23px" id="remark" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </br>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <center>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit">
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

So I want to disable submit button if issue quantity is more than bal quantity and remain enable if issue quantity is less than bal quantity. And I am getting bal quantity on change of item code from ajax call. So how Do I do it??

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    /**
      * the submit handler...
      */
    function checkBeforeSubmit() {
        // build your own condition ... :)
        if(CONDITION == false) {
            alert("You can not submit...");
        }else {
            // all is good ? so we submit the form ....
            document.myForm.submit();
        }
    }
</script>
<form name="myForm" action="add.php" method="post">
...
     <!-- i have changed the type from submit to button and add a handler to execute basic JavaScript function-->
     <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="checkBeforeSubmit();">
</form>
```

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo : i've already changed  it from submit to button :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not you try yo Add/remove disabled attribute to the submit button on qtty change.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code...

```
$('#issuequ').blur(function(){
                var issueqty = $(this).val();
                var bal = $('#bal').val();
                if(issueqty > bal){
                    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
                } else if (issueqty < bal){
                    $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
        });
```

I am here disabling submit on change of issuequ otherwise remain active.